# Laço if com css no JQuery

Tags: jquery, css

```
$('#label-user').click(function(){
    if ($('#label-user').style.display != 'none') {
        $('#label-user').css('display', 'none');
    }       
});
```

bom, o `jquery` não consegue ler a parte `$('#label-user').style.display != 'none'`, e não sei como substituir por algo que o jquery reconheça, procurei na documentação dele, mas não consegui encontrar nada

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sintaxe `.style.display` é para JavaScript nativo, como estás a usar jQuery seria `.css('display') != 'none'`.

Podes também fazer tudo em nativo dentro da callback:

```
$('#label-user').click(function(){
    if (this.style.display != 'none') {
        this.style.display = 'none';
    }       
});
```

Ou usando jQuery com [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/):

```
$('#label-user').click(function(){
    $(this).hide();     
});
```

Na verdade parece-me que bastaria

```
$('#label-user').click(function(){
     this.style.display = 'none';     
});
```

pois um elemento escondido não dá para clicar de qualquer maneira...

Comment: assim q liberar dou como resposta certa, vlw man :D

Comment: Uma observação, se você não quiser usar o .toggle(), que mostra ao clicar, e esconde ao clicar novamente. Use o .hide(), Que só habilita o processo de esconder.

Comment: @ThiagoYoithi não é possivel clicar num elemento com `display: none;`.

Comment: @Sergio, sim, exatamente por isso. Estou dando a alternativa do hide() por fazer mais sentido no contexto que ele apresentou. Qual seria o motivo dele usar .toggle() em um evento de clique onde o alvo é o próprio $(this)? Considerando que ele não vai conseguir clicar novamente depois de já estar escondido? Faz mais sentido usar o hide(), pois ele vai simplesmente esconder o elemento, sem permitir mais interações para este botão (que já não vai estar na tela mesmo). Foi só algo que passou pela minha mente aqui, rsrsrs... Me corrija se eu estiver deixando passar algo.

Comment: @ThiagoYoithi o `.hide()` também faz `display: none;` -> https://jsfiddle.net/trpqrjpb/

Comment: @Sergio, sim eu sei, todas essas funções, show(), hide(), toggle(). Todos eles fazem uso da propriedade display:none; do css. Meu ponto não é esse. Meu ponto é que não faz sentido usar o toggle() em um elemento que pode vir a ficar escondido, já que não será possível reativá-lo (isso se tratando de um evento de click com o alvo $(this)).

Comment: @ThiagoYoithi ah, compreendi, tens razão, semanticamente é mais correto usar o `.hide()`, é isso certo? Vou corrigir.

Comment: @Sergio Exatamente! Valeu por compreender.

Comment: @ThiagoYoithi obrigado pela paciência :P aqui já é noite e o cansaço faz a cabeça mais lenta :)